# ASP.NET MVC: DropDownList grouped by name not id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have a dropdown list for locations which is currently grouped by country in an ASP MVC program. 
The locations' drop down list is populated using the following line in my ViewModel:

```
ViewBag.Locations = new MultiSelectList(db.tblLocations, "LocationID", "LocationName", "CountryID");
```

Currently, the drop down list displays the countries as their IDs rather than by name.

e.g. 
1 
Location 
Location 
Location 
2 
Location 
Location

Is there a way to have the countries display in the drop down by name instead of ID?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

**EDIT:**  
**tblLocations**: 
LocationID 
LocationName 
CountryID

**tblCountries** 
CountryID 
CountryName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
ViewBag.Locations = new MultiSelectList(db.tblLocations, "LocationID", "LocationName", "tblCountries.CountryName");
```

but you need to include the tblCountries in tblLocations